# Activate the scroll in the code position: fixed; in css

Tags: html, css, scroll, position, fixed

I have a page where I've fixed the menu on the right. I want this section to be scrolled when it's full. I've tried this and it's impossible for me, so I need your help.
Note: from the overflow-y:scroll; I used it but did not have any results.
Is there a solution to this problem that I can apply to the fixed section and see the rest?

```css
.cbp-spmenu {
  background: #47a3da;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<nav class="cbp-spmenu" id="cbp-spmenu-s2">
  <h3>Menu</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: ***so I want to help you***.. Why would I need help?.. By the way post your code (html,css). ^_^

Comment: indexed Codes Tnx ;)

Comment: By the way, your code here does not reproduce the screenshot precisely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the menu has an unrestricted height, so no matter how big you make the content, it will never get full! Sure, it will grow larger than the window, but that doesn't matter to a fixed element.

Solution: give the menu a max-height, the size of which can be whatever you want. In my example, it's the height of the body.

```css
body, html {
  height:100%; margin:0;  /* to make sure we know how much 100% is */
}

.cbp-spmenu {
  background: #47a3da;
  position: fixed;
  max-height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  padding-right:2em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="cbp-spmenu" id="cbp-spmenu-s2">
  <h3>Menu</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Tnx Man Your Code is Work

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, can you mark it as the solution by clicking the checkmark to the left. Then it will n o longer turn up under unsolved questions.